# Suming a value for Fiscal Year when YY, MM and DD are are stored separately in SQL

Tags: sql, sum

Ok, I need some help with this. I think I may have been looking at this too long and its messing with my brain. I have a table, we'll call it Goals. In this table I have the following 4 columns:

StaffID example (123)
Syear example (2011)
Smonth example (7)
SGoal  example (104.2)

What I need is to sum the SGoal column for Fiscal Year, ie months 7-12 of one year and 1-6 of the next. Problem is I need this to be looping and by that I mean it cant be year specific. I will be using this query to run a report in BIZ for years to come. So I think it may be able to be done 2 ways, either through a query or modifying the table somehow. Either way, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? You want ot make two new columns.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to put the fiscal year calculation into a View but here's one way to do it in a query

```
SELECT staffid, syear+(((smonth+1)&8)/8) as fiscalyear, sum(sgoal) AS 'sum' 
FROM goals 
GROUP BY staffid, syear+(((smonth+1)&8)/8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, although storing the fiscal year would be a better and more elegant solution.

```
select staffId, fiscal_year, sum(sGoal) from (
select staffid, sGoal, if (sMonth > 6, sYear, sYear-1) as fiscal_year
  from goals ) as fiscal
group by staffId, fiscal_year
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64b39/2)